# Groovy HttpBuilder - Don't send negotiate authorization

Tags: groovy, single-sign-on, httpbuilder, negotiate

I'm having problem connect with s so (shibboleth to be specific) .
I'm using HTTP Builder on groovy and once i Get 401 i need to send Authorization Negotiate,
but It just don't send!
 I tried to define the header manually or with the HTTP builder authentication methods  , still nothing..
any help?

Comment: Any sample code, minimal working example?

Comment: 'HTTPBuilder  hb =new HTTPBuilder("uri")'
 'hb.auth.ntlm("user", "pass", "ws", "domain")'
 'hb.request(GET) {..'

Comment: It's much better idea to edit the post content and add sample code there.

Comment: it dosen't works either if i add manually the header . because when it get redirect to the page that response 401 the http builder fall on unauthorized exception instead of resend the request with the authorization @Opal

Answer (score 0):

fixed after upgrade HTTP client and HTTP builder jar to the newest